# Какие есть средства для просмотра PDF-файла

Tags: javafx, pdf, поиск-библиотек

Пытаюсь сделать просмотр pdf-файлов средствами java. Я так понял что стандартными средствами не получиться и нашел jPDFViewerFX.jar от Qoppa Software но в судя по всему он не бесплатный так как на всех страницах по диагонали стоит "фирменный лейбл"

Исходный код реализуется просто

```
PDFViewer pdfViewer = new PDFViewer();
pdfViewer.setSplitVisible(false);
pdfViewer.setToolBarVisible(false);
pdfViewer.loadPDF("C:\\pdffile.pdf");
anchpPDFReadder.getChildren().add(pdfViewer);
```

Есть ли другие бесплатные компоненты (библиотеки) для просмотра pdf-файлов. Желательно с примером.

Comment: Схожий вопрос с ответом (и примером) на англоязычной версии форума: [Displaying pdf in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207116/displaying-pdf-in-javafx)

Comment: Благодарю за отклик. я почти решил данную задачу при помощи компонента (библиотеки) org.apache.pdfbox и компонента Pagination. как только доработаю сразу же поделюсь своим методом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою задачу из источника https://github.com/torutk/pdfviewer/tree/master/src/pdfviewer при помощи org.apache.pdfbox и Pagination.

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Controller controller = loader.getController();
    controller.start();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Pdffile");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

PdfModel.java

```
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class PdfModel {

private PDDocument document;

private PDFRenderer renderer;

PdfModel(Path path) {
    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(path.toFile());
        renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException("PDDocument thorws IOException file=" + path, ex);
    }
}

int numPages() {
    return document.getPages().getCount();
}

Image getImage(int pageNumber) {
    BufferedImage pageImage;
    try {
        pageImage = renderer.renderImage(pageNumber);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException("PDFRenderer throws IOException", ex);
    }
    return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(pageImage, null);
}
}
```

Controller.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Controller {


@FXML
private Pagination pagination;

private PdfModel pdfModel;

public void start(){

    pdfModel = new PdfModel(Paths.get("c:\\pdffile.pdf"));
    pagination.setPageCount(pdfModel.numPages());
    pagination.setPageFactory(index -> new ImageView(pdfModel.getImage(index)));
}
}
```